# Asp.net MVC Routing w/ string parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I'm learning asp.net, and can't solve a rather simple problem for a while.

Have the RouteConfig.cs file with the following content:

```
public class RouteConfig {
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And got the controller with the content:

```
...
[Route("image/show/{uuid}")]
public ActionResult Show(string uuid) {
    return View(uuid);
}
...
```

[And the result when I try to open this url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceGwg.png)

Thanks in advance for the response!

Comment: there is no path found that you have take in attribute routing.

Comment: ok, but why is that? If I change the Show fn-s parameter to int i.e.:Show(int uuid). Then the same url -with a number as parameter at the end of course - works, and does the routing just fine. So it seems to me that the root cause of the problem is that the parameters type is string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its your following line creating issue

```
return View(uuid);
```

This line taking the **ViewResult View(string viewName)** overload of controller. It is considering the uuid variable you passed-in as a viewname and tries to find the view file by that name.

As a workaround you can change that line to

```
return View((object)uuid);
```

This will take correct overload **ViewResult View(object model)**
or store the uuid in viewbag and return the view as

```
return View();
```

off course, you still need Show.cshtml file in your View/Image directory.

Answer (score -1):

The error says that it cannot find the cshtml file in Views/Images/sdfsd.cshtml.

Add that file and it should work